# Where can I take my ultralight aircraft?

Tags: faa-regulations, ultralight

I know many airports do not allow ultralight aircraft but can I take it to work, home, or to the bar? What is the limits of freedoms of travel in an ultralight?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What regulations are in place for ultralight vehicles flying over US national parks?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/42844/what-regulations-are-in-place-for-ultralight-vehicles-flying-over-us-national-pa)

Comment: I don't think the picture you posted fits the definition of an ultralight in the United States.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Workhorse_SureFly  "The 70 mph (110 km/h) hybrid electric has a 200-hp gasoline generator giving up to 70 mi (110 km) range over 1 hour. It has four propeller arms, each with two electric contra-rotating propellers powered by a gas turbine or piston engine generator along a battery pack. Targeting a price of $200,000, it can lift a 400 lb (180 kg) payload and include a ballistic parachute.

The SureFly would operate as a conventional helicopter, like the similarly priced two-seat Robinson R22, but would be easier to fly and safer with its integral parachute. "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from a more specific answer by @Pondlife to a question about ultralights and National Parks:

> For ultralights specifically, the regulations are in [14 CFR 103](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?tpl=/ecfrbrowse/Title14/14cfr103_main_02.tpl) which has only a few very simple restrictions on where ultralights can operate. 103.15 says you can't operate over a congested area or a crowd of people and other restrictions are the obvious ones: don't fly near airports without ATC approval, don't enter restricted airspace, and do follow NOTAMs.

Comment: I understand you were giving a basic-level answer but actually for MOST airports without control towers there is no need to get ATC approval before flying an ultralight there.